# Oracle SQL: Using WHERE LIKE but for specific whole words / REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I have a table of invoices with cost identifiers saved in a specific way, non always standard, like below:

```
ID | SYMBOL | COST_IDS
---+--------+-------------------
 1 | FV01   | '1076219, 1081419'
 2 | FV02   | '107621,123421'
 3 | FV03   | '111521; 107621'
```

I would like to find invoices for a specific cost identifier.

The structure of the cost is (4 **or more** digits)+(2 year digits)

In Test case: `107621`, the desired output would be ID: `2 and 3`.

`SELECT *  FROM INVOICES  WHERE COST_IDS like '%107621%'`
Is a wrong approach.

I found that I need to use `REGEXP_LIKE` and I am struggling with it. I know I need to find the whole world exactly, but not necessarily on the beginning.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: this seems to work in most cases, but fails with the end of the string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INVOICES 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COST_IDS, '[^|\s|,|;]107621[$|\s|,|;]')
```

Also is there a way to mark 'non-digit' character instead of writing specifically `\s|,|;`?

Why is `$` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\D` to match a non-digit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   INVOICES
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(COST_IDS, '(^|\D)107621(\D|$)')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoices (ID, SYMBOL, COST_IDS) AS
SELECT 1, 'FV01', '1076219, 1081419' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'FV02', '107621,123421' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'FV03', '111521; 107621' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | SYMBOL | COST_IDS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | FV02 | 107621,123421 |
> | 3 | FV03 | 111521; 107621 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98824c954c5ddd4d07d7c406e9b042f4)*

---

Your regular expression does not work as:

- `[^|\s|,|;]` matches a single character that is **not** either `|` or `\` or `s` or `|` or `,` or `|` or `;`
- `[$|\s|,|;]` matches a single character that is either `$` or `|` or `\` or `s` or `|` or `,` or `|` or `;`

If you want to match either the start-of-the-string or a white space character or a comma or a semi-colon then you want the regular expression `(^|\s|[,;])`.

Similarly, if you want to match end-of-the-string or a white space character or a comma or a semi-colon then you want the regular expression `($|\s|[,;])`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Also, thanks for detailed explanation and fiddle link!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL Select statement considering you have two seperated portions for `cost_ids`, or presuming only one type of seperator for each `cost_ids` values even if there are more portions

```sql
WITH inv AS
(
 SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(cost_ids,'[[:punct:]]+') AS symbol2, cost_ids
   FROM invoices
)
 SELECT DISTINCT id
   FROM inv   
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(cost_ids,'[^'''||symbol2||''' ]+',1,level) = '107621' 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(cost_ids,symbol2) + 1 
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id
```

where the seperator symbol determined initially with the name `symbol2` through use of `[[:punct:]]` posix which is used to extract the punctuation characters.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=335de9292c4238249491b63dae9b0c1f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank You, I analysed it and i think that i get the idea. Maybe I was not clear in my example, the length of `COST_IDS` can vary (maybe one or 10+ costs in a string), same as the separators - the string is composed from more than one source until it gets to the final table.
Also I learned something new today, thanks!.

Comment: you're welcome @MichałMoskal , have a nice study!